# Get simple name of type in Julia?

Tags: types, printing, julia

Say I have

```
struct MyStruct{T,U}
  a::T
  b::U
end
```

I'd like to define a custom `show` which eliminates a lot of noise from the full type.

E.g. if I create the following:

```
z = MyStruct((a=1,b=2),rand(5))
```

then `typeof` shows much more than I want:

```
julia> typeof(z)
MyStruct{NamedTuple{(:a, :b), Tuple{Int64, Int64}}, Vector{Float64}}
```

How can I programmatically get just `MyStruct` from `z` into a string?

Comment: The `typeof` result is very long because that's the concrete type of the instance `z`. `MyStruct` is an abstract type, specifically an iterated union (`UnionAll`) of types with varying parameters `T,U`. That may be fine for printing purposes, but just be aware that when `z` and `z2` both print `MyStruct`, it's very possible that `typeof(z) != typeof(z2)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some lengthy discussions on Discourse [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/extract-type-name-only-from-parametric-type/14188/24) and [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/stripping-parameter-from-parametric-types/8293/14), which provide at least these two solutions (the second one generalising the first):

```
julia> Base.typename(typeof(z)).wrapper
MyStruct

julia> name(::Type{T}) where {T} = (isempty(T.parameters) ? T : T.name.wrapper)
name (generic function with 1 method)

julia> name(typeof(z))
MyStruct
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a string/symbol representation, you could use:

```
julia> nameof(Array{Int64, 1}
:Array

julia>nameof(typeof(z))
:MyStruct
```